# subscribe to switchMap RXJS

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am getting 2 syntax errors with the following code:

```
handleTypeahead = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
    text$.pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      debounceTime(500),
      .tap((term) => this.target = text$),
    // tap((term) => console.log("handleTypeahead", term)),
    // tap((term) => this.onTypeahead.emit(term)),
    /*map((term: string) => [])*/
    /*map((term: string) => term === '' ? [] : this.data)*/
    .switchMap(term => term === '' ? [] : this.data)
  ).subscribe((term) => this.onTypeahead.emit(term))

  }
```

1)by `debounceTime` - "expression expected".
2)by `.subscribe` - "Unresolved function or method subscribe()"
I tried this without the `pipe` operator but also have syntax errors, very new to RXJS but having a lot of issues getting this right.
v2:

```
handleTypeahead = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
    text$
      distinctUntilChanged(),
    debounceTime(500),
      .tap((term) => this.target = text$),
    // tap((term) => console.log("handleTypeahead", term)),
    // tap((term) => this.onTypeahead.emit(term)),
    /*map((term: string) => [])*/
    /*map((term: string) => term === '' ? [] : this.data)*/
    .switchMap(term => term === '' ? [] : this.data)
      .subscribe((term) => this.onTypeahead.emit(term))
  }
```

Here I am getting just error num#2 any help appreciated (will upvote of course)

Comment: removing the dots before .tap and .switchMap should help

Comment: tried this see my comment below.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the dots before `.tap` and `.switchMap` should works:

```js
text$.pipe(
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  debounceTime(500),
  tap(term => this.target = text$),
  switchMap(term => term === '' ? [] : this.data)
).subscribe(term => this.onTypeahead.emit(term));
```

Comment: Tried this and I get: "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined"

Comment: that is a whole another problem. obviously handleTypeahead function is being called with an undefined parameter. it is not possible to elaborate more without seeing the source code. please provide a stackblitz example.